# Why ProgressDialog Box gives NULL?

Tags: android, progressdialog

Here is my code Below. Here i m running a thread with a ProgressBar with a caption.

In run() of thread, if my internet connection is working then the ELSE part gets execute & dismiss that ProgressBar. But if my internet connection is not working then IF pat gets execute, here i m getting null exception when i try to dismiss ProgressBar. I have also added is null check **if(m_ProgressDialog == null)**, and prints DialobBox in NULL..

Whats happening with my code.? ProgressBar dismissing in ELSE part but in IF is throw NULL Exception...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....................
.....................
//some CODE //
.....................
.....................
viewOrders = new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if(!utilityFunctions.HaveNetworkConnection(SplashScreenActivity.this)) //checking internet connection
                        {
                            Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "NO Connecttion");
                            //updateUI(0);
                            if(m_ProgressDialog == null)
                                Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "DialogBox is NULL");
                            else
                                m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();

                            Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "Dismissed");
                            handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {                                  
                            try {                                   
                                m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();                                                                 
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e1) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }                       


                            Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "Starting Program");                    

                            startActivity(mainIntent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                private Handler handler = new Handler()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        //super.dispatchMessage(msg);
                        super.handleMessage(msg);
                        updateUI(msg.what);
                    }
                };  
            };

            Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
            thread.start();
            m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Getting required data from server. This is an one time activity...", true);
}



public void updateUI(int code){
        Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "updateUI");
        if(code == 0)
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Unable to verify application signature. Please Check your internet connection & try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Unable to process request. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to declare `ProgressDialog()` at the top

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....................
.....................
//some CODE //
m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Please wait...", 
"Getting required data from server. This is an one time activity...", true);
.....................
viewOrders = new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                      if(!utilityFunctions.HaveNetworkConnection(SplashScreenActivity.this)) //checking internet connection
                    {
                        Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "NO Connecttion");
                        //updateUI(0);
                        if(m_ProgressDialog == null)
                            Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "DialogBox is NULL");
                        else
                            m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();

                        Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "Dismissed");
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    }
                    else
                    {                                  
                        try {                                   
                            m_ProgressDialog.dismiss();                                                                 
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }                       


                        Intent mainIntent = new Intent().setClass(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "Starting Program");                    

                        startActivity(mainIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            private Handler handler = new Handler()
            {
                @Override
                public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                    //super.dispatchMessage(msg);
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    updateUI(msg.what);
                }
            };  
        };

        Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
        thread.start();

}



public void updateUI(int code){
    Log.i(UtilityFunctions.APP_TAG, "updateUI");
    if(code == 0)
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Unable to verify application   
signature. Please Check your internet connection & try again", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Unable to process request. ",  
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: In fact, creating the progress dialog BEFORE starting the thread, should work

Comment: Yes, Finuka is correct, the problem is that there's a chance that the Thread to run viewOrders may start immediately when its start() method is called, thus leaving m_ProgressDialog in a null state.

Comment: But @Kai & Finuka, Why ELSE part is not giving NULL exception error.?

Comment: The reason is that you're being lucky with the speed. Let me explain. You run the thread and the show the dialog. When you run the thread, the time that your app needs for checking the if condition and going to the else part, is enough. At this point, the main thread had enought time for creating the dialog. However, if you dont have internet, when you try to acccess to the dialog, the main thread didnt have time for creating it.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize progress dialog before calling thread.

```
m_ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Please wait...", "Getting required data from server. This is an one time activity...", true);
    Thread thread =  new Thread(null, viewOrders, "MagentoBackground");
    thread.start();
```

Hope this helpfull...